Image is resized wrong in Carousel After Updating to SDK 52 in React Native Expo
After updating to Expo SDK 52, images in the carousel are no longer displayed correctly, often appearing cropped or misaligned, especially for portrait-oriented images. This issue seems to stem from changes in how images are rendered or resized in the new SDK version. The goal is to resolve this by ensuring all images fit fully within the carousel without any cropping or misalignment, but I am having trouble doing so. This forced update of SDK is causing me a lot of issues.

Code
    import * as React from "react";
    import { Animated, View } from "react-native";
    import { useSharedValue } from "react-native-reanimated";
    import Carousel, {
      ICarouselInstance,
      Pagination,
    } from "react-native-reanimated-carousel";
    
    import { window } from "../features/favourites/constants";
    
    const PAGE_WIDTH = window.width;
    
    function Test({
      images,
    }: {
      images: { original: string; thumbnail: string }[];
    }) {
      const progress = useSharedValue<number>(0);
      const ref = React.useRef<ICarouselInstance>(null);
    
      const onPressPagination = (index: number) => {
        ref.current?.scrollTo({
          count: index - progress.value,
          animated: true,
        });
      };
    
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Carousel
            ref={ref}
            vertical={false}
            width={PAGE_WIDTH}
            height={PAGE_WIDTH * 0.6}
            loop
            pagingEnabled
            snapEnabled
            autoPlay
            autoPlayInterval={2500}
            onProgressChange={(_, progressValue) => {
              progress.value = progressValue;
            }}
            mode="parallax"
            modeConfig={{
              parallaxScrollingScale: 0.9,
              parallaxScrollingOffset: 50,
            }}
            data={images}
            renderItem={({ index }) => (
              <View
                key={index}
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#fff",
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  width: PAGE_WIDTH / 1,
                  height: PAGE_WIDTH / 1.8,
                  shadowColor: "#000",
                  shadowOffset: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 4,
                  },
                  shadowOpacity: 0.34,
                  shadowRadius: 10.32,
                  elevation: 16,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <Animated.Image
                  source={{ uri: images[index].original }}
                  style={{
        width: PAGE_WIDTH / 1,
                height: PAGE_WIDTH / 1.8,
                borderRadius: 10,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                  }}
                  resizeMode={"cover"}
                />
              </View>
            )}
          />
    
          {Pagination && Pagination.Basic && (
            <Pagination.Basic
              progress={progress}
              data={images}
              dotStyle={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)" }}
              containerStyle={{ gap: 5, marginBottom: 10 }}
              onPress={onPressPagination}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    export default Test;

I also tried with react-native-snap-carousel, still is same problem.
This is package.json
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.5",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^4.0.0-canary.20",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",


I reviewed some parts of the code and found that some styling properties can be changed, specifically the one in Animated.Image, given that the Image class seems to require dimensions for the root class parameters, those can be given outside the style properties, and some other dimension values can as well be changed, please check on the comments for the modified lines below:
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Carousel
        ref={ref}
        vertical={false}
        width={PAGE_WIDTH}
        height={PAGE_WIDTH} //*0.6 may resize the inner Image to the 60% of the size
        loop
        pagingEnabled
        snapEnabled
        autoPlay
        autoPlayInterval={2500}
        onProgressChange={(_, progressValue) => {
          progress.value = progressValue;
        }}
        mode="parallax"
        modeConfig={{
          parallaxScrollingScale: 0.9,
          parallaxScrollingOffset: 50,
        }}
        data={images}
        renderItem={({ index }) => (
          <View
            key={index}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#fff",
              borderRadius: 10,
              width: 'auto', //changing this to auto may help to fit entire width of screen
              height: PAGE_WIDTH, // this PAGE_WIDTH / 1.8 tells the child view of component to be 180% of screen width which if landscape it may not be desired
              shadowColor: "#000",
              shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 4,
              },
              shadowOpacity: 0.34,
              shadowRadius: 10.32,
              elevation: 5,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Animated.Image
              source={{ uri: images[index].original }}
              width={PAGE_WIDTH}
              height={PAGE_WIDTH / 1.8}
              style={{
              borderRadius: 10,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              }}
              resizeMode={"cover"}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      />

      {Pagination && Pagination.Basic && (
        <Pagination.Basic
          progress={progress}
          data={images}
          dotStyle={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)" }}
          containerStyle={{ gap: 5, marginBottom: 10 }}
          onPress={onPressPagination}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

export default Test;

A different approach that simulates what Carousel does is the following:
import { Dimensions, ScrollView } from 'react-native';  

const { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT, width: SCREEN_WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window');  
const scrollViewRef = useRef(null); 

const carouselItems = [  
  { icon: faDollar, label: "Money" },  
  { icon: faLanguage, label: "Language" },  
  { icon: faToolbox, label: "Tools" },  
];  

const handleScroll = (event) => {  
  const contentOffsetX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;  
  const index = Math.floor(contentOffsetX / SCREEN_WIDTH);  
  setCurrentIndex(index);  
};  

Provide style of flexGrow: 1, like the one below:
contentContainer: {
  flexGrow: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  paddingHorizontal: 70, // Adjust padding as needed
},

And here you can add a similar animated behavior to Carousel:
<ScrollView  
  horizontal  
  pagingEnabled
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  onScroll={handleScroll}  
  scrollEventThrottle={16}  
  ref={scrollViewRef}  
  snapToAlignment="center"
  decelerationRate="fast"
  contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}  
  >  
  {carouselItems.map((item, index) => renderItem(item, index))}  
</ScrollView>

This is the render item function:
const renderItem = (item, index) => {  
  let navigateTo;  
  switch (item.label) {  
    case "Money":  
      navigateTo = 'ScreenPage1'; //another ScreenPage1.tsx 
      break;  
    case "Language":  
      navigateTo = 'ScreenPage2';  //another ScreenPage2.tsx
      break;  
    case "Tools":  
      navigateTo = 'ScreenPage3';  //another ScreenPage3.tsx
      break;  
    default:  
      navigateTo = null;  
  }  

